# Openerp comparing 2 field value and display result in another field

Tags: field, odoo

I have inherit product.product to get available products so:

```
'qty_stock': fields.related('rented_product_id', 'qty_available', type='float', relation='product.product', string="En stosck", readonly=True),
'qty_1': fields.related('rented_product_id', 'incoming_qty', type='integer', relation='product.product', string="Résrver", readonly=True),
'qty_2': fields.related('rented_product_id', 'outgoing_qty', type='integer', relation='product.product', string="Sortant", readonly=True),
'qty_state': fields.selection([('libre','Libre'),('louee','Louée'),('reserver','Réservée')], 'Status', readonly=True
```

I want to display in field 'qty_state':

```
if 'qty_1' > 0 and 'qty_2 < 0 : display 'reserver'
if 'qty_1' > 0 and 'qty_2 = 0 : display 'louee'
if 'qty_1' = 0 and 'qty_2 = 0 : display 'libre'
```

help please

Answer (score 1):

You must use a fields.function instead of a fields.selection, like this :

```
def _get_qty_state(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    res = {}
    for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        # Put 'libre' as default value
        res[product.id] = 'libre'
        if product.qty_1 > 0 and product.qty_2 < 0:
            res[product.id] = 'reserver'
        elif product.qty_1 > 0 and product.qty_2 == 0:
            res[product.id] = 'louee'
    return res
```

And in '_columns':

```
'qty_state': fields.function(
    _get_qty_state,
    method=True,
    type='selection',
    selection=[('libre','Libre'),('louee','Louée'),('reserver','Réservée')],
    string='Status',
    readonly=True,
    store=False,
),
```

OR

You can keep the fields.selection and feel it by overriding the 'default_get' method.